# Comma separated values count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count

Table Pattern has single column with the following values:

```
NewsletteridPattern
------------
%50%
%51%
```

Table B has the following values:

```
SubscriberId NewsletterIdCsv
------------ -----------------
47421584     51
45551047     50,51
925606902    50
47775985     51
```

I have the following query which basically counts the comma seperated values by using the pattern:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEB t WITH (nolock)
JOIN Patterns p ON (t.NewsletteridPattern LIKE p.pattern)
```

The problem is that the count is incorrect as for example my pattern has %50% and %51% and thus the row number 2 from Table B should be counted twice, however with my query it is only once, how do I fx that?

**EDIT :**
I forgot to add DISTINCT in my original query which was causing the issue:

```
SELECT Count(Distinct Subscriberid)
FROM TABLEB t WITH (nolock)
JOIN Patterns p ON (t.NewsletteridPattern LIKE p.pattern)
```

Comment: This query is counting the rows correctly - see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9cd3/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mocked up your data as such:

```
create table #pattern (pattern varchar(50))

insert into #pattern values ('%50%')
insert into #pattern values ('%51%')

create table #subscriber (id varchar(50), newsletter varchar(50))

insert into #subscriber values ('47421584', '51')
insert into #subscriber values ('45551047', '50,51')
insert into #subscriber values ('925606902', '50')
insert into #subscriber values ('47775985', '51')

SELECT pattern, COUNT(*) AS Counter
FROM #subscriber t WITH (nolock)
    JOIN #pattern p ON (t.newsletter LIKE p.pattern)
GROUP BY pattern
```

And my select statement returns:

```
pattern  Counter
-------  -------
%50%        2

%51%        3
```

What is your final goal?  Are you just concerned about counting the number of rows by pattern or are you trying to do a select of rows by pattern?

Comment: I updated my question and removing distinct was answer itself form the count . Thanks !